# An error occurred initializing the application server: Failed to locate pgAdmin4.py, terminating server thread

Tags: python

I am getting this error:

> An error occurred initializing the application server: Failed to locate pgAdmin4.py, terminating server thread.

As it fails it will prompt to adjust the python and application path but I read an answer on Stack Overflow where the person said he deleted the path it worked for him and did so but it still gave me the same error and I don't see the prompt again.

So I went to pgAdmin official site only to see that if it fails I must enter python and application path. How can I configure the paths for the pgAmin. I am using Fedora 27.

Answer (score 2):

Try to just delete the config file.  You may have an old one from a previous install.

`rm ~/.config/pgadmin/pgadmin4.conf`

Answer (score 1):

> As it fails it will prompt to adjust the python and application path but read an answer on stackoverflow where the person said he deleted the path it worked for him and did so but it still gave me the same error and i don't see the prompt again

**Probably your first error was actually**

```
An error occurred initialising the application server:
Failed to launch the application server, server thread exiting.
```

**Most likely you missing some dep like `python3-flask-babelex`**

e.g on fedora install

```
sudo dnf install python3-flask-babelex
```

**You see following error (one you mentioned) when you have misconfigured user config file. Which was created after you edited default values from prompt**

```
An error occurred initializing the application server:
Failed to locate pgAdmin4.py, terminating server thread.
```

**This error can be solved by either fixing your config or deleting it to use default values:**

e.g. on Fedora checking that your user config is correct

```bash
vi ~/.config/pgadmin/pgadmin4.conf
```

Primarily check that path variables in `[General]` section are ok.

```
# example
[General]
ApplicationPath=/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pgadmin4-web/
PythonPath=/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages:/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, the example [General] section did the trick for me. I didn't have an ~/.config/pgadmin/pgadmin4.conf.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the solution was to `sudo dnf remove pgadmin4*` then `sudo find / -iname "*pgadmin4*"` and delete any scraps lying around, then `sudo dnf install pgadmin4*` - everything is now working fine.